# Anyone have some sample code to create a OLE DB Provider in C# that can be used by any OLE DB app?

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a custom database that I want to write an OLE DB provider for but I was hoping to do it in C#.

I found these 2 sites but all examples are in C.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715920(v=VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713643(v=VS.85).aspx

I want it to show up in the provider list.
Like in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

[Inside .NET Managed Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810268.aspx)

Comment: your article is for **dotnet1.1** and is intresting if you want to create a databaseprovider that can be used **only by a .net application**. Since dotnet2.0 this is much easier with System.Data.Common.DbConncetion, DbCommand, ... instead of IDbConnection,.... If understood  @donny v correct he wants a oledb-provider that can be used by any oledb-app.